# How to bind progress bar (use Ladda) with a button after button clicks in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, progress-bar

I have a progress bar and a button click. Now the progress bar is not linked with the button. so how can I ensure: when the button clicks,then the progress bar starts; when the result is retrieved from the server, then the progress bar stops? Could some body help?

I want to try to have some hidden field as flag to notify progress bar, but have not got time to try it yet.

HTML button is here:

```
<section class="progress-demo">
            <button id="sendRequest_1" onclick="SendRequest(1)" type="button" class="btn btn-danger ladda-button" data-style="expand-left"><span class="ladda-label">Send</span></button></section>
```

Progress bar is using

```
<script src="js/spin.min.js"></script><script src="js/ladda.min.js"></script>
```

Progress bar is here:

```
      <script>
        // Bind normal buttons
       Ladda.bind( 'section:not(.progress-demo) button', { timeout: 2500 } );

        //Ladda.bind( 'input[type=submit]' );

        // Bind progress buttons and simulate loading progress
        Ladda.bind( 'section.progress-demo button', {
            callback: function( instance ) {
                var progress = 0;
                var interval = setInterval( function() {
                    progress = Math.min( progress + Math.random() * 0.1, 1 );
                    instance.setProgress( progress );
                    if( progress === 1 ) {
                        instance.stop();
                        clearInterval( interval );
                    }
                }, 200 );
            }
        } );
```

Button click funtion is here.

```
function SendRequest(i){
alert("button clicked!");
//call post to get server response
... say 1s to get response
//how to bind it to progress bar when server response is back??
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
...
var l = Ladda.bind( 'section:not(.progress-demo) button', { timeout: 2500 } );
...

function SendRequest(i){
  $.ajax({
    url: "some.php",
    success: function(data){
      l.stop();
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi, I try to use this  var l = Ladda.create("#getsystem"); but it gives me error - ladda.min.js:8 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function. I already includes <script src="js/spin.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/ladda.min.js"></script>, and it gives me this error anyway?

Comment: i do not see this code at your first message. Did you changed code? Show me your code.

Comment: sorry, #getsystem is a button id, I can use the #sendRequest_1 instead. The issue happens to me is: Chrome developer tool will tell me: undefined function, for l.stop(); from your suggestion. But I already include 2 js files there in the html page. Don't know what's wrong. Thanks.

Comment: even if this post is old, im having the same type of trouble.. Did you find a solution to it?